# Tool Equivalent to Flight recorder for Hotspot JDK6

Tags: jvm-hotspot, jrockit

I am aware that Hotspot JDK7 has both Java Mission Control and flight recording bundled with it. But, as per my application requirement, I am bound to use Hotspot JDK6. I could monitor the Hotspot6 JVM performance using JMC. But flight recording is disabled for Hotspot6 JVM. Is there any other tool equivalent to it for Hotspot6?

Comment: anybody have idea about i3 monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing equivalent, but you can try jconsole or jvisualvm (in the bin directory).